# Kivy - Border and Font weight

Tags: python, fonts, kivy, border

I am working on a project, and made a wireframe before getting into Kivy for its development.

I managed to put round edges to the button, but am not able to put border around it.

Moreover, I couldn't find any way to increase the font weight beyond `bold:true`.

[image]

(Although my requirement is quite clear and there is no point in sharing code, yet I am sharing for those who want to see how this has been done)

I defined a SmoothButton to add radius to the button edges

`<SmoothButton@Button>:
    background_color:(0,0,0,0)
    background_normal:''
    back_color: (0.565, 0.557, 0.698,0.8)
    border_radius:[0,35,0,35]
    font_name:'Comic'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:self.back_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size:self.size
            pos:self.pos
            radius:self.border_radius`

And used it as my buttons:

`<MainWindow>:`

```
name:"main"
GridLayout:
    cols:3


SmoothButton:
    text:"Find\nZone"
    bold: True
    on_release:app.root.current="FindWindow"
    pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"y":0.35}
    size_hint:0.2,0.2
    font_size:20
    color:1,1,1,1
    text_size: self.size     
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'center'
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
    border: 0, 32, 0, 32
    size: 200, 64
    center: root.width / 2, root.height / 2

SmoothButton:
    text:"Understand\nZone"

    on_release:app.root.current="UnderstandWindow"
    pos_hint:{"x":0.4,"y":0.35}
    size_hint:0.2,0.2
    font_size:20
    color:1,1,1,1
    text_size: self.size     
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'center'
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
    # background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#58AE6F')
    border:0.1,0.1,0.2,0.4
SmoothButton:
    text:"Knowledge\nZone"

    on_release:app.root.current="KnowWindow"
    pos_hint:{"x":0.7,"y":0.35}
    size_hint:0.2,0.2
    font_size:20
    color:1,1,1,1
    text_size: self.size     
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'center'
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
    border:0.1,0.1,0.2,0.4
```

Comment: You can draw a border with a Line instruction. I don't think Kivy supports any more subtle font weight settings, but I don't know if this functionality is available (just not exposed) in the font backends.

Comment: Typically, borders are drawn by painting the SmoothButton canvas with a RoundedRectangle of the border color, then painting it again with  a slightly smaller RoundedRectangle of the background color.

Comment: @inclement Drawing a line wouldn't help, coz I can't curve the lines in alternate corners.

Comment: @Ritveak Yes you can

Comment: @inclement can you please hint some code here? It would be of great help, thanks!